# Is there a way to launch one time use .Jsx script files like you can in After effects?

Tags: adobe-premiere, adobe-creative-cloud

In After Effects, you can place `.Jsx` script files at `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2023\Support Files\Scripts`
Then on the next time you load the program, you can find the scripts on the main menu bar, `File` > `Scripts`.

I am looking for **Premier Pro**'s equivalent of this features. I have looked at its program files directories, there is a scripts folder there, with a similar structure to AE:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro 2023\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro 2023\Scripts\Startup
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro 2023\Scripts\Hello World.jsx
```

I have placed the `Hello World.Jsx` file, there but I am not been able to find a way to launch the script within Premier itself.

I have searching everywhere on how to do THIS specifically. I have comes across two solutions.

1. To use a hidden CEP panel to communicate with Premier Pro
2. To run `.Jsx` code from the command line with Premiere, `PremPro /C es.processFile "C:\TEMP\Test.jsx"`

For the first solution, the learning curve and time needed to set this up is simply too steep. The second, it will only work on Premier when its first about to open, not on a already running Premier instance.

I just want to run simple scripts from within Premier, like you can out of the box with

- Photoshop
- Illustrator
- After Effects

I don't mind granting any 'script execution' security permissions.

Thank you for any help.